# Error: Primary Outlet is already registered

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angular-material

I have a scenario that I want to load the components when I click on angular material tab. When I click on first tab it is loading correctly whereas second tab it is giving an error saying   `Primary Outlet is already registered` I am using angular 1.5 components.

**Component**:

```
    (function() {
    app.component('tabComponent', {
        templateUrl: 'components/tabComponent/tabComponent.html',
        bindings: {
            $router: '<'
        },
        controller: tabComponentCtrl,
        $routeConfig: [{
            path: '/tab1-component',
            name: 'Tab1Component',
            component: 'tab1Component',
            useAsDefault: true
        }, {
            path: '/tab2-component',
            name: 'Tab2Component',
            component: 'tab2Component'
        }]
    });

    function tabComponentCtrl() {
        var scope = this;
        scope.aTabs = [{
            name: 'Tab1Component',
            component: 'tab1Component'
        }, {
            name: 'Tab2Component',
            component: 'tab2Component'
        }];
        scope.fnGetTab = function(name) {
            this.$router.navigate([name]);
        }
    }
})();
```

Here tabs are in ng-repeat.
**HTML**:

```
<md-content class="tabs-color" layout-margin="30px">
    <md-tabs md-dynamic-height="" md-border-bottom="">
        <div ng-repeat="tab in $ctrl.aTabs">
            <md-tab label="{{tab.name}}" md-on-select="$ctrl.fnGetTab(tab.name)">
                <md-content class="md-padding">
                    <ng-outlet></ng-outlet>
                </md-content>
            </md-tab>
        </div>
    </md-tabs>
</md-content>
```

Any help will be appreciated.